# NumberPicker in AlertDialog always activates keyboard. How to disable this?

Tags: android, dialog, android-widget, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

To all,

I am trying to get a simple NumberPicker to work in a AlertDialog. The problem is that whenever I increase/decrease the value in the numberpicker, the keyboard activates.

There are many posts describing this problem, but none of the suggestions work. 
I have tried:

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden"
```

And

```
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(currentView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

And

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
     WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

I have tried calling these functions before and after initialization (dialog.show ()), on keypress events (using listeners obviously), etc. but no luck so far.

The complete code:

popup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <NumberPicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myNumber"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden"   
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the calling function:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder =  new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        return;
    } }); 
builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        return;
    } }); 
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
builder.setView (view);

final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create ();
NumberPicker picker = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.myNumber);
picker.setMinValue(0);
picker.setMaxValue(999);

dialog.getWindow().
    setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
dialog.show();
```

Any help appreciated

Barry

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Actually, although the solution above works perfectly, there is an easier way.

```
picker.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

This is all that is needed. Anyway, thanks for the replies!!!! :-)

Comment: You can also set this in XML: android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

Answer (score 3):

Since there is no access to NumberPicker buttons, it's "impossible" to do.

I made fast dirty hack to deal with it.

First add focus eater to layout, in this case Button with 0 size:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <NumberPicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myNumber"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

We need to catch event of clicking on incement/decrement buttons, I chose OnValueChangedListener, couldn't find something better.

```
    EditText edit = null;
    try {
        final Field[] fields = picker.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field f : fields) {
            if (EditText.class.equals(f.getType())) {
                f.setAccessible(true);
                edit = (EditText) f.get(picker);
            }
        }
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
    if (edit != null) {
        final EditText finalEdit = edit;
        final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        picker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker numberPicker, int i, int i1) {
                dialog.findViewById(R.id.myBtn).requestFocusFromTouch();
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(finalEdit.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        });
    }
```

This is not recommended solution. I hope someone would find something better. 
Use only for educational purpose ;-)

Answer (score 1):

the `android:configChanges` attribute belongs in your `Manifest.xml` file, not the layout. But if you are hiding the keyboard from there, you are probably best of using

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

You should also try to use `getWindow()` on your `Activity` rather than just the `Dialog` and see if that helps. This is probably the best solution as the first one (hiding from the manifest) will keep the keyboard hidden throughout the entire Activity.

Comment: Hello Jave, Thanks for your answer and your insights on Manifest vs layout xmls. The thing is, however, that I cannot add these parameters to the layout, since the layout is basically a form. The numberpicker is a popup (alertdialog) on this form and I only need to disable the keyboard on this dialog, not the entire activity. This is what you already menion by the way :-) The getWindow on the activity was something I already tried and does unfortunately not help

Answer (score 0):

XML:

```
<NumberPicker
    ...
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" />
```